# Need to run collection multiple iterations and need to run csv file which I have declared data for json body

Tags: csv, postman, newman

I have exported collection of postman. One request has declare a variable inside the json body . I have csv file with data for that variable. Now I want to run collection with multiple iterations with csv file (data) in Newman command line

Tried this for run multiple times

`newman run collection_exported.json -n 3`

It runs multiple iterations (For this I did not include that variable)

Json body has below variable

```
"value":"{{medinfovalues}}"
```

and csv file has below values

[image]

Comment: You will need to tell it what csv file to use, just like you would in the runner. It doesn't know that automatically. :)

Comment: How to add it ? Are there any command in newman ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to use the `-d <source>` or `--iteration-data <source>` cli flag to tell Newman the location of the data file.

For example:

`newman run collection_exported.json -d "filepath/myDataFile.csv" -n 3`

More information about all the different cli flags can be found here:

https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman#newman-run-collection-file-source-options